# object required even though variable is integer

Tags: excel, vba

I have no idea why I am Getting run time error 424 (object required ) for trying to set image count = number in cell. Any Help would be appreciated

```
Public Function InsertPictureInCell() As Object


         ImageCount = CInt(sheetImages.Cells(1, 4))
         Dim x As Object


            sheetImages.Paste
    Set x = sheetImages.Shapes(Selection)
    x.top = [C4].top
    x.Left = [C4].Left
    x.Height = [C4].Height
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop [C3].Height * ImageCount 

        'sheetImages.Shapes(picname).IncrementTop [C3].Height * ImageCount
        sheetImages.Cells(ImageCount + 2, 2) = CStr(x.Name)
        'sheetProject.Cells(12, 2) = PictureFileName
End Function
```

Comment: Turn on `Option Explicit` at the top of this module. It looks like you have not declared `sheetImages` (or actually *any* of your variables). Apart from that, there is no assignment *to* `sheetImages`, so it's initialized as an empty variant, which will raise the 424 error if you treat it like an object, because it's not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sheetImages` appears to be a worksheet, but I don't see were it is **Set**

Comment: `sheetImages` appears  to be an empty variant, although it's presumably intended to be a worksheet :)

Comment: I might be stupid. I have all of those set in the main function and when testing this one the i didn't call the function that set those values. It's working now. Thanks

Comment: @DaIndian2040 I usually `Dim` objects like this as **Public** as possible.  Once they are `Set`, they are visible across the board.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not declared `sheetImages` (or actually *any* of your variables).

Apart from that, there is no assignment *to* `sheetImages`, so unless it's in scope from being initilaized elsewhere, it's initialized in this function scope as an empty variant, which will raise the 424 error if you treat it like an object, because it's not an object.

Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module to help enforce variable declaration (and alert you to typos with a compile error).